# Why <pubDate> tag is lowercase but the closing tag is correct?

Tags: php, rss

here Im again with a big issue.

I have a blog but RSS feeds are showing error
[image]

As you see I get `<pubdate> date </pubDate>`

I generate the RSS with php, here is the full code
:

```
    <?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n"; ?>
<rss version="2.0"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
     xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
<channel>
    <title><?= $feedName; ?></title>
    <link><?= $feedUrl; ?></link>
    <description><?= convertToXmlCharacter(xml_convert($pageDescription)); ?></description>
    <dc:language><?= $pageLanguage; ?></dc:language>
    <dc:creator><?= $creatorEmail; ?></dc:creator>
    <dc:rights><?= convertToXmlCharacter(xml_convert($settings->copyright)); ?></dc:rights>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<item>
<title><?= convertToXmlCharacter(xml_convert($post->title)); ?></title>
<link><?= generatePostUrl($post); ?></link>
<guid><?= generatePostUrl($post); ?></guid>
<description><![CDATA[ <?= $post->summary; ?> ]]></description>
<?php
if (!empty($post->image_url)):
$imagePath = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $post->image_url ?? ''); ?>
<enclosure url="<?= $imagePath; ?>" length="49398" type="image/jpeg"/>
<?php else:
$imagePath = base_url($post->image_mid);
if (!empty($imagePath)) {
$fileSize = @filesize(FCPATH . $post->image_mid);
}
$imagePath = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $imagePath ?? '');
if (!empty($imagePath)):?>
<enclosure url="<?= $imagePath; ?>" length="<?= (isset($fileSize)) ? $fileSize : '12'; ?>" type="image/jpeg"/>
<?php endif;
endif; ?>
<pubDate><?= date('r', strtotime($post->created_at)); ?></pubDate>
<dc:creator><?= convertToXmlCharacter($post->username); ?></dc:creator>
</item>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

As you can see, the code is right, but I dont know why is this happening.

PHP version 7.4

Comment: Can't be explained by the code you shared, I think. Please double-check that it is actually correct in the script file you have on the server. If that is not the issue, then presumably something else must be going on outside of that script, but it would be very weird for anything to make _that_ kind of arbitrary modification to your output.

Answer (score 0):

try add header `Content-Type: application/xml`